# Spring Boot - Data JPA - download Large Lob files from DB

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have written a spring boot web/rest application to handle a legacy system (DB tables), this application does the following:

1. user create a bill request through a REST WS.
2. My rest app store the request to Legacy DB Tables.
3. another system(X) (out my control) reads the record and generate a zip file.
4. X system then store the file in our table (zip file and file name).
5. user can now download the file using my application.

the issue here some bill files are large (1-2 GB) and I'm getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

this happens in Hibernate when I'm trying to select the file content

now how can I let the user download a large file without getting above error? please check below for POJO classes and Repos

Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class EbillStatus implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid")  
@Column(name="EBILL_STATUS_ID")
private String id;

@Column(name="CORPORATE_EBILL_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String corporateEbillId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="COMPLETION_DATETIME")
private Date completionDatetime;

@Column(name="FILENAME", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String filename;
@Lob
private byte[] fileContent;

@Column(name="USER_ID")
private String username;

@Column(name="STATUS_ID")
private Integer status;

@Column(name="BILL_COUNT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer billCount;

private Integer accountCount;
}
```

The Repository:

```
public interface EbillStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<EbillStatus, String> {
EbillStatus findByCorporateEbill(CorporateEbill corporateEbill);

@Query(value="select s FROM EbillStatus s WHERE s.corporateEbillId=?1")
EbillStatus findFile(String corporateEbillId);
}
```

Service Method Implementation:

```
@Service
public class EbillServiceImpl implements EbillService {

private EbillStatusRepository statusRepo;

@Autowired
public EbillServiceImpl(EbillStatusRepository statusRepo){
    this.statusRepo = statusRepo;
}

@Override
public EbillFileModel getEbillFile(String username, String eBillId) throws NotFoundException{
    EbillStatus ebill= statusRepo.findFile(eBillId);
    if(ebill == null || !isEbillFileAvailable(ebill.getStatus()))
        throw new NotFoundException("file not available for username: "+username+", eBillId: "+ eBillId);
    return new EbillFileModel(ebill.getFilename(), ebill.getFileContent());
}

private boolean isEbillFileAvailable(Integer status){
    return COMPLETED.equals(String.valueOf(status)) || DELIVERED.equals(String.valueOf(status));
}
}
```

Pojo Class which is given to the controller

```
public class EbillFileModel {
private String fileName;
private byte[] fileContent;
public EbillFileModel(String fileName, byte[] fileContent) {
    super();
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.fileContent = fileContent;
}
public EbillFileModel() {
    super();
}
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
public byte[] getFileContent() {
    return fileContent;
}
public void setFileContent(byte[] fileContent) {
    this.fileContent = fileContent;
}   
}
```

Controller method to Download the file

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{username}/order/{eBillId}/download", produces = "application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadEbillFile(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String eBillId)
        throws IOException, NotFoundException {
    EbillFileModel file = ebillservice.getEbillFile(username, eBillId);     
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, CACHE_CONTROL_VAL);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA,PRAGMA_VAL);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(ATTACHMENT, file.getFileName());
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, ZERO);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_ZIP)
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(file.getFileContent()));
}
```

**Summary and Notes:**

- *I cannot change the system design and how it works, I just wrote a Web/REST application on top of it.*
- I'm using Spring boot 1.5.1.RELEASE and java 8
- the packaging is a WAR file deployed on JBoss EAP 7
- what is the best way to download large files stored in DB.

Comment: Any news? I have pretty the same problem

Comment: Can you show your frontend side which is responsbile for downloading file?

Comment: There is no front-end.. it is a Rest service, I think the issue is I'm loading the file into the memory while it should be read in chunks.. how that what I'm looking for

Comment: Any solution you got ??